# Write a plugin for SonarPython

Tags: java, python, function, maven, sonarqube

I am trying to write a plugin for SonarPython. The plugin shall count the number of lines a function or method (wihtout comments) and then assign it to a group depeding on the number of lines. My problem is I never write a Plugin for Sonarqube before. I tried with the help of "SonarQube in Action" by *MANNING
G. Ann Campbell* and *Patroklos P. Papapetrou* but the explained way in this book seems to be deprecated. On the page of [sonarqube](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+SonarJS#CustomRulesforSonarJS-ImplementaRule) there are examples for Java, PHP and JavaScript but not for Python. Furthermore, my Maven project can't found the groupid: org.sonarsource.python. Therefore, the most documentation are useless for me.

Has anyone of you already written a plugin for SonarPython and has some advice ?

Also, I take a look at a example from the orinal code [site](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python/blob/master/python-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/python/checks/TooManyLinesInFileCheck.java).

I hope some of you may help me.

Comment: What does it mean to "assign it to a group depeding on the number of lines"? What kind of group? What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: I want to ensure that functions aren't too long. Therefore, if a function has less than X lines everything is fine. If a function has more than X but less than Y lines it shal maybe be refactored. Finally, if lines has more than Y lines it shall be refactored.

Answer (score 1):

SonarPython does not support custom plugins. That's why you didn't find any documentation on how to do that.

You can try to define a custom rule with XPath. See the related [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules+using+XPath).

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out.